# Python Tkinter: Call function after long press spacebar for 1 second

Tags: python, python-2.7, events, tkinter, bind

I would like to create a function for my GUI using key-press events. My goal is to allow a function to be called if user presses the spacebar  for more than 1 second, and abort the function if key releases **within this 1 second**.

How do I do this?

Feel free to edit my example:

```
from Tkinter import Tk, Frame

class Application(Frame):

   def __init__(self, parent):
      Frame.__init__(self, parent)
      self.parent = parent
      self.parent.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (800, 300, 0, 0))
      self.parent.resizable(0, 0)

      self.pack(expand = True)
      self.parent.bind('<Control-s>', self.printer)
   def printer(self, event = None):
      print "Hello World"

def main():
   root = Tk()
   Application(root)
   root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Python 2.7, Linux

Reference: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm

Answer (score 3):

This is either going to be really easy, or really hard. Which it is depends on several factors. Conceptually, the solution is simple:

1. on the press of the space key, use `after` to schedule a job to run in the future
2. on release of the key, cancel the job.

Where it gets hard is that some systems, when you keep a key pressed, will continue to auto-repeat either the keypress (so you'll get a stream of presses in a row, without a release) or a pair of presses and releases (you'll get a steady stream of press/release events). This might be done at the keyboard hardware level, or it might be done by the OS.

Comment: bind("<space>") checks for press of space key, what about its release?

Comment: you can use `<KeyRelease-space>` (and `KeyPress-space` if you want to be pedantic)

Comment: I have edited my question for more details. I want to abort the function on key release ONLY IF it is within that 1 second.

Comment: My system auto-repeats key-press and key-release when long press space key. I can't think of a way to capture this repeating in my function. Any clues?

Comment: I'm thinking of measuring the amount of key presses and releases in one second, set that as the condition

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is an old question, but I was able to implement a solution with a bit of trial-and-error, and thought I'd post it here in case it helps anybody else. (Note that I've only tested this with Python 3.6 and Windows, but I've got a similar solution working with long mouse button presses on Linux, so I'm assuming this transfers).

```
from tkinter import Tk, Frame

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.parent.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (800, 300, 0, 0))
        self.parent.resizable(0, 0)

        self.pack(expand = True)
        self._short_press = None
        self.parent.bind('<KeyPress-space>', self.on_press_space)
        self.parent.bind('<KeyRelease-space>', self.on_release_space)

    # set timer for long press
    def on_press_space(self, event):
        if self._short_press is None: # only set timer if a key press is not ongoing
            self._short_press = True
            self._do_space_longpress = self.after(1000, self.do_space_longpress)

    # if it was a short press, cancel event. If it was a long press, event already happened
    def on_release_space(self, event):
        if self._short_press:
            self.cancel_do_space_longpress()

    # do long press action
    def do_space_longpress(self):
        self.cancel_do_space_longpress() # cancel any outstanding timers, if they exist
        print('long press')

    # cancels long press events
    def cancel_do_space_longpress(self):
        self._short_press = None
        if self._do_space_longpress:
            self.parent.after_cancel(self._do_space_longpress)

def main():
    root = Tk()
    Application(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```